# Kubernetes : Access dashboard from remote browser

Tags: kubernetes

I have a small Kubernetes cluster that I have built following (mostly) [this tuto](https://www.profiq.com/kubernetes-cluster-setup-using-virtual-machines/).

So I have a master and some slaves on Virtual Box CentOS VMs, and I want to access the Kubernetes dashboard from a browser on my host machine.

So I used [this file](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/blob/master/aio/deploy/recommended/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml) to create my dashboard service, deployment, role binding, ... . And started a proxy as follow :

```
 kubectl proxy --port=9999 --address=[MASTER_IP_ADDRESS] --accept-hosts="^*$"
```

I then tried to access the dashboard from my browser using the URL : `http://[MASTER_IP_ADDRESS]:9999/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kubernetes-dashboard`, but I get the following json displayed :

```
{
"kind": "Service",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "kubernetes-dashboard",
    "namespace": "kube-system",
    "selfLink": "/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kubernetes-dashboard",
    "uid": "a0b1d1bc-5adf-11e9-a89e-080027cef83a",
    "resourceVersion": "569",
    "creationTimestamp": "2019-04-09T15:53:33Z",
    "labels": {
      "k8s-app": "kubernetes-dashboard"
    },
    "annotations": {
      "kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration": "{\"apiVersion\":\"v1\",\"kind\":\"Service\",\"metadata\":{\"annotations\":{},\"labels\":{\"k8s-app\":\"kubernetes-dashboard\"},\"name\":\"kubernetes-dashboard\",\"namespace\":\"kube-system\"},\"spec\":{\"ports\":[{\"port\":443,\"targetPort\":8443}],\"selector\":{\"k8s-app\":\"kubernetes-dashboard\"}}}\n"
    }
  },
  "spec": {
    "ports": [
      {
        "protocol": "TCP",
        "port": 443,
        "targetPort": 8443
      }
    ],
    "selector": {
      "k8s-app": "kubernetes-dashboard"
    },
    "clusterIP": "10.102.168.28",
    "type": "ClusterIP",
    "sessionAffinity": "None"
  },
  "status": {
    "loadBalancer": {

    }
  }
}
```

How can I access my dashboard ?

Note :

- When I browse the URL `http://192.168.99.20:9999/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy`, I get a `503 no endpoints available for service \"kubernetes-dashboard\"` error.

EDIT :

After some digging up, I think that the problem is deeper thant just 'I can't access the dashboard'. I created another question with all the informations that you can [find here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55609377/kubernetes-coredns-pods-stuck-in-pending-status-cannot-start-the-dashboard).

Comment: `503 no endpoints available for service \"kubernetes-dashboard\"` tells to you than your dashboard is not ready. You have to check the pod status with `kubectl get pod` and `kubectl logs POD_NAME`. Your container is not ready to receive traffic.

Comment: You are right. 
For some reason, my service kubernetes-dashboard is stuck in pending state. I don't know why yet, but I also have dns pods stuck in pending state which look like this issue : https://github.com/play-with-docker/play-with-docker/issues/301.

Answer (score 0):

To access Kubernetes dashboard through kubectl proxy

1. Confirm that your kubernetes dashboard is running and Ready

e.g.
`kubectl -n kube-system get pods | grep dashboard`

2. Follow official instructions to access the dashboard:

- e.g. `kubectl proxy` (proxies to 8001) by default
- visit the dashboard

http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/

The UI can only be accessed from the machine where the command is executed. See kubectl proxy --help for more options.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/web-ui-dashboard/