# Kubernetes coredns pods stuck in Pending status. Cannot start the dashboard

Tags: kubernetes, coredns

I am building a Kubernetes cluster following this [tutorial](https://www.profiq.com/kubernetes-cluster-setup-using-virtual-machines/), and I have troubles to access the Kubernetes dashboard. I already created another question about it that you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55596900/kubernetes-access-dashboard-from-remote-browser), but while digging up into my cluster, I think that the problem might be somewhere else and that's why I create a new question.

I start my master, by running the following commands:

```
> kubeadm reset 
> kubeadm init --apiserver-advertise-address=[MASTER_IP] > file.txt
> tail -2 file.txt > join.sh # I keep this file for later

> kubectl apply -f https://git.io/weave-kube/

> kubectl -n kube-system get pod
NAME                                READY   STATUS  RESTARTS    AGE
coredns-fb8b8dccf-kb2zq             0/1     Pending 0           2m46s
coredns-fb8b8dccf-nnc5n             0/1     Pending 0           2m46s
etcd-kubemaster                     1/1     Running 0           93s
kube-apiserver-kubemaster           1/1     Running 0           93s
kube-controller-manager-kubemaster  1/1     Running 0           113s
kube-proxy-lxhvs                    1/1     Running 0           2m46s
kube-scheduler-kubemaster           1/1     Running 0           93s
```

Here we can see that I have two `coredns` pods stuck in Pending state forever, and when I run the command :

```
> kubectl -n kube-system describe pod coredns-fb8b8dccf-kb2zq
```

I can see in the Events part the following Warning :

```
Failed Scheduling : 0/1 nodes are available 1 node(s) had taints that the pod didn't tolerate.
```

Since it is a Warning and not and Error, and that as a Kubernetes newbie, `taints` does not mean much to me, I tried to connect a node to the master (using the previously saved command) :

```
> cat join.sh
kubeadm join [MASTER_IP]:6443 --token [TOKEN] \
    --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:[ANOTHER_TOKEN]

> ssh [USER]@[WORKER_IP] 'bash' < join.sh

This node has joined the cluster.
```

On the master, I check that the node is connected:

```
> kubectl get nodes 
NAME        STATUS      ROLES   AGE     VERSION
kubemaster  NotReady    master  13m     v1.14.1
kubeslave1  NotReady    <none>  31s     v1.14.1
```

And I check my pods :

```
> kubectl -n kube-system get pod
NAME                                READY   STATUS              RESTARTS    AGE
coredns-fb8b8dccf-kb2zq             0/1     Pending             0           14m
coredns-fb8b8dccf-nnc5n             0/1     Pending             0           14m
etcd-kubemaster                     1/1     Running             0           13m
kube-apiserver-kubemaster           1/1     Running             0           13m
kube-controller-manager-kubemaster  1/1     Running             0           13m
kube-proxy-lxhvs                    1/1     Running             0           14m
kube-proxy-xllx4                    0/1     ContainerCreating   0           2m16s
kube-scheduler-kubemaster           1/1     Running             0           13m
```

We can see that another kube-proxy pod have been created and is stuck in ContainerCreating status.

And when I am doing a describe again :

```
kubectl -n kube-system describe pod kube-proxy-xllx4
```

I can see in the Events part multiple identical Warnings :

```
Failed create pod sandbox : rpx error: code = Unknown desc = failed pulling image "k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.1": Get https://k8s.gcr.io/v1/_ping: dial tcp: lookup k8s.gcr.io on [::1]:53 read up [::1]43133->[::1]:53: read: connection refused
```

Here are my repositories :

```
docker image ls
REPOSITORY                          TAG     
k8s.gcr.io/kube-proxy               v1.14.1 
k8s.gcr.io/kube-apiserver           v1.14.1 
k8s.gcr.io/kube-controller-manager  v1.14.1 
k8s.gcr.io/kube-scheduler           v1.14.1 
k8s.gcr.io/coredns                  1.3.1   
k8s.gcr.io/etcd                     3.3.10  
k8s.gcr.io/pause                    3.1
```

And so, for the dashboard part, I tried to start it with the command

```
> kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/master/aio/deploy/recommended/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml
```

But the dashboard pod is stuck in Pending state.

```
kubectl -n kube-system get pod
NAME                                    READY   STATUS              RESTARTS    AGE
coredns-fb8b8dccf-kb2zq                 0/1     Pending             0           40m
coredns-fb8b8dccf-nnc5n                 0/1     Pending             0           40m
etcd-kubemaster                         1/1     Running             0           38m
kube-apiserver-kubemaster               1/1     Running             0           38m
kube-controller-manager-kubemaster      1/1     Running             0           39m
kube-proxy-lxhvs                        1/1     Running             0           40m
kube-proxy-xllx4                        0/1     ContainerCreating   0           27m
kube-scheduler-kubemaster               1/1     Running             0           38m
kubernetes-dashboard-5f7b999d65-qn8qn   1/1     Pending             0           8s
```

So, event though my problem originaly was that I cannot access to my dashboard, I guess that the real problem is deeper thant that.

I know that I just put a lot of information here, but I am a k8s beginner and I am completely lost on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an issue I experienced with `coredns` pods stuck in a pending mode when setting up your own cluster; which I resolve by adding pod network.

Looks like because there is no Network Addon installed, the nodes are taint as `not-ready`. Installing the Addon would remove the taints and the Pods will be able to schedule. In my case adding *flannel* fixed the issue.

EDIT: There is a note about this in the official [k8s documentation - Create cluster with kubeadm](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm/#pod-network):

> The network must be deployed before any applications.  ***Also, CoreDNS
>   will not start up before a network is installed.***  kubeadm only
>   supports Container Network Interface (CNI) based networks (and does
>   not support kubenet).

Comment: Isn't it what the `kubectl apply -f https://git.io/weave-kube/` is for ?

Comment: I replaced the previous command by `kubectl apply -f "https://cloud.weave.works/k8s/net?k8s-version=$(kubectl version | base64 | tr -d '\n')"`, and now weave-net appear in my pods.
And since that, my coredns pods magically started Running (as you said :) )

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is the opposite of a deep or serious issue. This is a trivial issue. Always you see a pod stuck on `Pending` state, it means the scheduler is having a hard time to schedule the pod; mostly because there are no enough resources on the node.

In your case it is a `taint` that has the node, and your pod doesn't have the toleration. What you have to do is to describe the node and get the taint:

```
kubectl describe node | grep -i taints
```

Note: you might have more then one taint. So you might want to do `kubectl describe no NODE` since with grep you will only see one taint.

Once you get the taint, that will be something like `hello=world:NoSchedule`; which means `key=value:effect`, you will have to add a `toleration` section in your `Deployment`. This is an example `Deployment` so you can see how it should look like:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 10
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: nginx
        name: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: http
      tolerations:
      - effect: NoExecute       #NoSchedule, PreferNoSchedule
        key: node
        operator: Equal
        value: not-ready
        tolerationSeconds: 3600
```

As you can see there is the toleration section in the yaml. So, if I would have a node with `node=not-ready:NoExecute` taint, no pod would be able to be scheduled on that node, unless would have this toleration.

Also you can remove the `taint`, if you don need it. To remove a `taint` you would describe the node, get the `key` of the taint and do:

```
kubectl taint node NODE key-
```

Hope it makes sense. Just add this section to your deployment, and it will work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! 

On my node kubemaster, I have the following taints : `node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute`,  `node-role.kubernetes.io/master:NoSchedule`, `node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoSchedule`.
The thing I don't understand is that I only executed the command `kubeadm init --apiserver-advertise-address=[MASTER_IP]`. I don't have any YAML file at this point. Do I need to create a new Deployment file ?

Comment: Yeah, these taints make sense. It is for ensuring that no Pod is going to run on master node (if it is not intended), and no Pods should be running on a node with certain issues (not ready node). Just add the tolerations as explained to your deployments (e.g. core-dns), and it should work. P.S. your issue has nothing to do with network plugins. At least this one your are describing.

Comment: Well, actualy the fact is that my coredns is stuck in pending with a Warning about not tolerated taints, and as soon as I correctly started a network plugin, the coredns status go to Running. I don't know if it makes sense, but this is what happened.

Comment: That makes zero sense to me. Unless your node was taint as `not-ready` because of the plugin was not installed. In that case the taint would be removed once the node is ready. If you run `kubectl describe node NODE` you still have the taints?

Comment: Now I only have the taint `node-role.kubernetes.io/master:NoSchedule`

Comment: That does make sense to me. The node was dynamically taint.

Answer (score 0):

Set up the flannel network tool.

Running commands:

```
$ sysctl net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables=1
$ kubectl apply -f
```

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/62e44c867a2846fefb68bd5f178daf4da3095ccb/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml